# Suppressing default output from gdb when stepping between instructions

Tags: debugging, gdb

When I step through a debugging session with gdb, it prints out some information for me. How do I stop this. Here's an example:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x100000d4 in ?? ()
(gdb) si
0x100000d8 in ?? ()
(gdb) si
0x100000dc in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Here I want to remove the lines that say `0x100000d8 in ?? ()`. I can't find anything in the documentation about suppressing this output. Any ideas?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

A bit arcane solution is to define a function that turns on "logging redirect", then steps the instruction and lastly, turns off logging. Example:

```
define stepix
   set logging redirect on
   set logging file /tmp/whatever
   set logging on
   si
   set logging off
end
```

but that solution will suppress all output, not just the `0x100000d8 in ?? ()`. Might not fit your need/taste. I don't think suppressing that output is possible.

Comment: ...you can of course `set logging file /dev/null` so it doesn't send anything to disk, either.

Answer (score 1):

you can suppress printing the `0x100000d8` with `set print address off`. looking at the [source](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gdb/stack.c?annotate=1.163.2.1.4.1&cvsroot=src) (search for *`static void print_frame (...)`*), i don't think that suppressing the rest possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is now 2016, and I have an ugly solution for those who want to selectively disable a command output. I don't know how recent your `gdb` should be.

Instead of

```
(gdb) stepi
```

try this

```
(gdb) python gdb.execute("stepi", to_string=True)
```

It feels like such a basic feature, please share if you have a better way, in particular one which doesn't rely on `python`. I'd really like to avoid the (likely) performance hit when running the `stepi` in a loop.